# CSS Stylesheet with Python CGI

Tags: python, html, css, cgi

I am running a python cgi script in a web browser. All works fine, but as soon as the code finishes executing, all css styling disappears (the html form still appears and works fine). How can I fix this? Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
    <title>Python Index Match</title>
</head>

<body>
     <form action="/cgi-bin/form.py">
      <tag>Welcome!</tag>
      <p class="text">Please browse for your company file:   <input type="file" name="file1" value="Browse"> </p>
      <span class="btn"></span>
      <p class="text">Please browse for your price export file:   <input type="file" name="file2" value="Browse"> </p>
      <span class="btn"></span>
      <p class="text">What company is this file for?     <select name="dropdown"> </p>
        <option></option>
        <option value="...">...</option>
        <option value="...">...</option>
      </select>
      What would you like to name your new file? (With extension) <input type="text" name="result"><br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Here are the before and after images:
[image: Before code runs]
[image: After code finishes running]

Answer (score 0):

Your CGI script should issue an HTTP "redirect" code to the page you want to show.

```
# Do not "print(...)" above this
location = "http://where/you/want/to/browse"  # URL may be relative
# The first two "print(...)"
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print("Location: {}".format(location))
print()  # Empty line (important)
print("<html><body>Redirecting, please wait.</body></html>")
```

Comment: This is what I have:                                                                   
print("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r")
print('\r')

Comment: The important thing is the `print("Location ...")` line that should tell the browser to load the page at the given URL.

Comment: And use the Firefox or Chrome development tools to inspect the real dialog (headers, content) between the server and the browser and see what is wrong.